# Echad Veshiv'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred seventy-one?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible.*

*At some undetermined point in the future, at least a day from now, I will:*

- *Vote up all interesting, relevant answers.*
- *Accept what I consider the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

271 is the days of pregnancy.

רות: ד. יג.
ויקח בעז את רות ותהי לו לאשה ויבא אליה ויתן יהוה לה **הריון** ותלד בן

הריון = 271

[Niddah 38a-b](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=5338&size=1)

Answer (score 3):

Years ago that [Rabbi Levi Yitzchak of Berditchev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi_Yitzchok_of_Berditchev) was born.

Comment: This is obsolete now.

Comment: Aw, fiddlesticks.

Answer (score 3):

271 years after the first Beis Hamikdash's foundations were laid, a new era in its history began, with Chizkiyahu's purifying it from the idolatry introduced by his father Achaz and urging the Jews to make it the center of their lives (II Chron. chs. 29-31).

(Construction on the Beis Hamikdash began in the fourth year of Shlomo's reign, in [2928](http://www.jewishamerica.com/ja/timeline/tem12pur.cfm) since Creation. Chizkiyahu began his program of improving Jewish life immediately on his accession to the throne, in [3199](http://www.jewishamerica.com/ja/timeline/tem12pur.cfm).)

Answer (score 2):

According to the Chofetz Chaim, brought in [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11044/how-many-of-the-613-mitzvos-are-we-able-to-do-currently), the number of Mitzvot one can do outside the land of Israel today (i.e. in exile).

Complement: [342](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/78317/2)

Answer (score -1):

271 is the numerical value of "Ani HaGever" (I am the man) and Yirmiyahu, who is the author of Eichah, and who laments, in 3:1, that he had to not only prophesy, but also "witnessed affliction by the rod of (HaShem's) anger."
(Artscroll Eichah pg. 33, note 1)