# Shnayim Veshiv'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred seventy-two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible.*

*At some undetermined point in the future, at least a day from now, I will:*

- *Vote up all interesting, relevant answers.*
- *Accept what I consider the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

*In case this is the last entry before Rosh Hashanna: Shanna Tova!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certain numbers in Hebrew are not written in the normal form. 15 would normally be written yud/hey, but because this spells a name of Hashem, it is customarily written tes/vav The same is true of tes/zayin, 16, instead of yud/vav.

The number **272** is also not written in the regular pattern, since the regular pattern would spell a word with a negative connotation. **272** would normally be spelled resh/ayin/bais which spells ra'av meaning "famine." Since the normal way to write this numbers spells a word with a negative connotation, it is written out of order.

Comment: I was going to write this by 270.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14079.

Answer (score 3):

There were 272 delegates to the B'nai B'rith convention in Fresno in June of 1947, according to [the *Southwestern Jewish Press*](http://sandiegojewishworld.com/2008-SDJW-Quarter%203/20080706-jewish-sunday161.html#histlasker).

272 is the *gimatriya* of *raev*, "hungry", and possibly the number of months someone's life was extended for being charitable, according to [Rabbi Moshe Bogomilsky](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/vedibarta-bam/47.htm).

Stealing [an answer of Gershon Gold's](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10228), it was possible to give birth on the 272d day of pregnancy, according to [*Sh'muel*](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=5337&size=1).

Answer (score 3):

Per [the Seder Olom Zuta](http://books.google.com/books?id=OBA2AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA69&dq=%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9D) from the Mabul till the Dor Haflaga was 272 years.

Answer (score 2):

The Arizal explains what we say in the Mussaf of Rosh Hashanah "איזו לרעב ואיזו לשובע" - "who will have famine and who will have plenty?", that the famine comes from the derivation of the gematria of רעב, which is 272, from the two names of G-d - א-להים י-ה-ו-ה by using the square gematria of א-להים, that is, (א + א-ל + א-לי + א-להי + א-להים) which equals 200,
plus the square gematria of י-ה-ו-ה which equals 72, thus totaling 272.

(The derivation used to get the gematria of שבע will have to wait until "Who knows 372?" :-)