# Why the custom to switch around negative-sounding numbers, such as שד?

Tags: number, history, minhag, jewish-books, writing-printing

Often in sefarim we find that if the number of the siman spells out something negative, such as siman 304 which has a letter value of שד, we switch it around so it no longer reads as a "bad" word. [Here's an example](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14265&st=&pgnum=511&hilite=) in the Tur. [Here's another](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14265&st=&pgnum=464&hilite=) and [another](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14265&st=&pgnum=461) and [another](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44395&st=&pgnum=702).

When and where did this custom originate? Did the original Tur have this configuration, or was it modified by later printers? Can it be found in earlier books?

Furthermore, does it *really* serve a purpose? How would it matter if a siman reads רעה?

Comment: Just wondering what exactly Ayin Hara has to do with anything?

Comment: @HachamGabriel its just my guess at where the answer will be headed.

Comment: @DoubleAA was [this example](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44395&st=&pgnum=702) which you added an older edition? Interestingly I noticed it has BOTH רע and it's flipside ער.

Comment: @Vram According to Hebrewbooks, yours were published in 1861 and mine in 1631.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10294.

Comment: Don't they also skip over "good" numbers?  Like various forms of G-d's name

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28385

Comment: A related, more specific question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33359

Answer (score 2):

I think this falls under categories such as lashon naki which do not have clear parameters ([Halachot of Lashon Naki (clean speech)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14257/halachot-of-lashon-naki-clean-speech))

Answer (score 0):

Because we avoid writing words which have a negative connotation as an attempt to disassociate Torah with negativity.

Comment: The question already said that. What are you adding?