# Altering the Spelling out the Hebrew Year

Tags: history, hebrew, calendar, aleph-bet-letters, acronyms

In 1983-1984, the Hebrew year was 5744.  Normally, the year would have been spelled out in Hebrew letters תשמ״ד, but according to my rabbi then, Rabbi Phillip Rabinowitz, zt'l, as pronounced the word would mean "annihilation" and therefore we should change the last two letters so that it reads תשד״ם. He told me that it had been done in earlier years when the spelling out of the year might portend something bad for the Jewish people.  What other years was the spelling of the Hebrew calendar year altered for this purpose?

Comment: תשד״ם or תשד״מ? In some systems, ם is 600

Comment: It's not just years of course. See the simonim in O Ch Hilchos Shabbos:  instead of  רעה it has ערה and instead of רעב it has ערב

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14079/759

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok In some editions, yes.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman -- I don't remember how calendars spelled it out that year, if any did.  It was 30 years ago.  BTW, the irony is Rabbi Rabinowitz was murdered that same year.

Comment: On a related note, see the W3C's old recommendation for CSS3 Hebrew ordered lists: http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-lists-20021107/#hebrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes the name changes because it spells a "bad" idea, but sometimes it's done because the other one is just nicer.

- 1910 - תר"ע became עת"ר (from Ra - bad)
- 1912 - תרע"ב became תער"ב (like [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/31687)) (from Rav - hunger)
- 1917 - תרע"ז became עזר"ת  (like [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/15739)) (Ezras - help)
- 1919 - תרע"ט became עטר"ת (like [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/15714)) (Ateres - crown)
- 1938 - תרצ"ח became תרח"צ (Tirtzach - kill)
- 1950 - ה,תש"י became השי"ת (Hashem Yisborech).
- 1991 - תשנ"א became תנש"א (like [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/16035)) (Tinose - Rule)

Surprisingly, 1944 stayed תש"ד (like [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/19806)) (Shin Daled spells Shed - daemon)

Comment: תנשא means rule? I think the focus there is on avoiding תשנא hate. And even if שד means demon, תשד doesn't.

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe.

Comment: I think it must have been 1938 that my Rav was referring to.  It is so appropriate that "kill" and that year be associated.

Comment: Any evidence that these changes would be made when the leading character was other than ת? Are any/all of these standard outside Chabad?

Comment: @DoubleAA תנשא would be "you shall be raised above", which can be a form of rulership but is not necessarily so

Comment: The year 1944 was truly a shin daled for the Yidden, at least in Europe.