# What is the problem with writing שט as a number?

Tags: number, aleph-bet-letters

In Hebrew, numbers are represented by letters.

When these letters spell out something unpleasant or undesirable, they are moved around. An example is שד which means “demon” becomes דש in the [Mishna Berurah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=188&hilite=) .

I see that also in [Mishna Berurah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=224) 
שט becomes טש but this is not universal as can be seen in this [סידור](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21833&st=&pgnum=58) - and for reference the same סידור [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21833&st=&pgnum=24) does change רעה (evil) to ערה.

What is the problem with spelling out שט?

Comment: Just FTR there is no universal agreement on which numbers (if any) ought be rewritten.

Comment: [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/?source=osdd#auto/en/%D7%A9%D7%82%D6%B5%D7%98) says it means "rebel or apostate".

Comment: @DoubleAA - and [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/?source=osdd#auto/en/%D7%A9%D7%82%D6%B5%D7%98) offers "floating" as an alternative. So we have an answer I think.

Comment: The latter meaning is the standard one in Tanach, eg [Jer 5:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1105.htm#1) or [Job 2:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2702.htm#2) and is seemingly not offensive. I don't know anything about the former meaning.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10682/3

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14079

Comment: @Double AA Is there really a difference between the "rebel" and "floating" meanings? See http://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%9F which suggests that the root שָׂטָן is , המקור בשורש שׁ־ו־ט, לפי הפסוק: "וַיַּעַן הַשָּׂטָן אֶת ה' וַיֹּאמַר מִשּׁוּט בָּאָרֶץ וּמֵהִתְהַלֵּךְ בָּהּ" (איוב א, ז)

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Google Translate uses a Sin not a Shin. I'm not familiar with that word, but they claim it means rebel.

Answer (score 2):

שֵׂטִים (also written סֵטִים) occurs in [Tehillim 101:3](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%90_%D7%92) and [Hoshea 5:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A2_%D7%94_%D7%91) and translates to something like "deeds/people that veer." Rashi on the verse from Hoshea connects this word to the root also found in the more common word סוטה‎ *sotah*:

> **סטים** - לשון כי תשטה אשתו (במדבר ה') לסור מן הדרך דישטולמנ"ט בלע"ז
>
> **Setim** - This language is used in the verse "When his wife goes astray (*tisteh*)" ([Bamidbar 5:12](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%22%D7%92_%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%91)), meaning "to veer from the path". In *La'az* this word is *distoulment*.

In both occurences the word has a negative connotation (and semantically is similar to the word חטאים in  the sense of "missing the mark") so it would make sense if this is why it is obfuscated in some books.

Incidentally, I think [Google Translate gives "rebel"](http://translate.google.com/?source=osdd#auto/en/%D7%A9%D7%82%D6%B5%D7%98) as a translation of שֵׂט because the verse from Hoshea is translated [in the King James Bible with the word "revolters."](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Hosea&chapter=5&verse=2)

See also: [Strong's Concordance H7846](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=H7846&t=RSV)

Answer (score -1):

It's the name of the prince of the demons

Comment: [Edit]ing in evidence for this claim would vastly improve your answer.