# Arba'a Va-arba'im Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred forty four?

### ארבעה וארבעים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 344? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 344, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Please, no answers that are just lazy gematria. Especially not with this number.

Comment: Isn't this off topic as a riddle?

Comment: @Loewian, the [problem with riddles](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/140/2) is that they intentionally hide information to make it fun to guess the answer, instead of providing as much information as possible to try to elicit good answers, which is what the SE Q&A model expects question posts to do. This post doesn't intentionally hide any information.

Comment: @loewian also this has generally been seen as grandfathered in regarding various standards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Minhagei Yeshurin - Siman 4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33772&st=&pgnum=24&hilite=) says the reason we say Aizehu Mekomon every day is there is no Machlokes - dispute in that Perek. It adds that this chapter has 344 words and is "Mishna Berura L'Moshe M'Sinai"; the 344 words + the recital = Moshe, this alludes that the Torah Sh'Baal Peh was given to Moshe at Sinai.

Answer (score 6):

344 is the least possible number of dates in the year on which a person in Israel is permitted to eat chamets. 353 days in a chaser year, minus 7 days of Pesach, and Tisha B'av and Yom Kippur. (The other fasts don't apply for the entire date.)

Answer (score 2):

Page 344 in sefarim is often written with the digits out of order to avoid writing שמד, destruction; it is thus written שדמ.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14079/759